# Is it possible to dynamically get application uri using application name from VCAP Services

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

Lets say we have a Spring Boot application deployed in Cloud Foundry called "app1" and if we need to get the URI of this application from another spring boot application say "app2" thats also deployed in Cloud Foundry on the same space. Is this possible by giving something like below in "app2" code

${vcap.application.app1.uris[0]} //If used this in the application.yml of app2

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do that. Since apps run inside their own containers, the environment variables are not shared among apps even if they are in same space.

If you know the routes which the app1 is using then you can use app2's application_uris[0] to replace and use.

Comment: Cool! So Apps properties cannot be shared between other apps like how we share the service properties between applications after binding as there no App binding concept here. Correct?

Comment: Exactly...  Service bindings are supported by CF hence properties of the binded services are created as a env variable. but there is no app binding concept hence, you cannot share env variables across apps. If you are using spring cloud then u may consider using Eureka service for service discovery from netflix oss.

Comment: If you need a quick and easy way to pass data between apps, like the URL for your service, you can bind a user provided service or use `cf set-env`.  Where you'd want to start looking at service discovery is when you need to dynamically discover and adapt to changes.  If you pass a URL in via a user provided service / env variable, you can only update that by updating the service / env variable and restarting apps that are using it.  Service discovery is dynamic and will adapt without requiring you to restart consuming services.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of an anti-pattern and I certainly wouldn't recommend having any application deployed with credentials to talk to the cloud controller. Using some sort of service discovery framework for this would be a much better fit, like [Spring Cloud Services' "Service Registry"](https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-3/common/service-registry/) or [Netflix's "Eureka"](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka)